# Overridden CellPainting in DataGridView displays content only after cell loses focus

Tags: winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have overridden the CellPainting in a WinForms DataGridView to display a specific image in a cell depending on various factors.

To give you some more details, in the CellPainting I am redrawing the content of a DataGricViewCheckBoxColumn; I want to display a green tick or red cross instead of the default black tick.

To draw the image I use:

`e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, new PointF(centreX - offsetX, centreY - offsetY));`

It works fine, but my green tick/red cross is only displayed **after** the cell loses focus. Is there a way to make it show as soon as I have clicked it, just like the standard checkbox does?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the `CellContentClick` event to toggle the value (true/false) of the current cell. The *CellContent* of a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` is the check box.

Assuming the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` is the first column:

```cs
private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        var s = sender as DataGridView;
        var b = s[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value == null
            ? true
            : (bool)s[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

        s[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = !b;
    }
}
```

If you prefer to toggle the value by clicking anywhere on the cell (not over the check box only), handle the `CellMouseClick` instead:

```cs
private void dgv_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        var s = sender as DataGridView;
        var b = s[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value == null
            ? true 
            : (bool)s[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

        s[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = !b;
        s.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
    }
}
```

Either way, the `CellPainting` event fires and the specified image is drawn as you click.

`CellPainting` example:

```cs
Bitmap bmp1 = Properties.Resources.GreenImage;
Bitmap bmp2 = Properties.Resources.RedImage;

private void dgv_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        var s = sender as DataGridView;

        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Background
            | DataGridViewPaintParts.Border
            | DataGridViewPaintParts.SelectionBackground
            | DataGridViewPaintParts.Focus
            | DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon);

        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            var r = new Rectangle((e.CellBounds.Width - 16) / 2 + e.CellBounds.X,
                (e.CellBounds.Height - 16) / 2 + e.CellBounds.Y, 16, 16);
            var b = (bool)e.Value;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(b ? bmp1 : bmp2, r);
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```